# Can't mount drive in Thunar anymore

Tags: arch-linux, thunar, polkit

Today, I got a `Not authorized to perform operation.` message when I tried to mount a drive in Thunar.

```
# cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udiskie.pkla 
[Local Users]
Identity=unix-group:storage
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

I'm in the `storage` group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules of this sort, whether `polkit` or `udev` are no longer necessary if you have an active session under systemd/logind. Originally, rules of this sort were a workaround for non-consolekit sessions, but now Arch has moved to systemd they are no longer necessary and are more likely to inhibit correct automounting behaviour rather than assist it.

You can check that you have an active session with:

```
loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID
```

which should show amongst its output:

```
Remote=no 
Active=yes
```

If this doesn't show, and you are not using a display manager, you need to ensure that when you start `X` your session is preserved—so `X` must be run on the same TTY where login occurred. See this entry on [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#Preserving_the_session).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://lampslave.ru/2-words-about-polkit/) to solve your problem you may add next lines to your `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/XX.rules`

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (action.id == 'org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system' &&  subject.user == '%username%') {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
);
```

replace `%username%` with the user you need to mount drives.

You can also permit mounting for the group of users. To do that insert next lines into your `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/XX.rules`:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (action.id == 'org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system' && subject.isInGroup('%groupname%')) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    }
);
```

where `%groupname%` is the group you want to make able to mount drives.